# How to make same gradient on two paths under and above specific shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

## How to make the same gradient on two paths under and above a specific shape?

[image: image with path]

Layer structure:

- the first layer contains the first path above
- group with circle and some stroke layers
- behind layer that contains the second part behind a circle

The issue is - I have a gradient on the front path and in the behind layer I choose a similar color and fill this out with it. In a result there is small issue with colors. Because paths were split I've got an issue after I export it to SVG like this:
[image]

Do you have any advice on how to do it? I tried to make a group and choose a gradient for the group but it's not possible because as a result, my circle will be behind or above a specific group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not split the gradient path. Hide a part of it with a clipping or opacity mask.An example:

[image]

The ring is the top layer. The black piece is inserted and used to hide a part of the ring as inverted clipping mask.

The perfectly fitting mask path can be got with pathfinder subtraction from the copy of the mid-shape.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **Clipping Mask**...

Draw an *extra* path around what you **want** to show on top.

[image]

Select this extra path and the shape you want on top and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu

[image]

The tricky part is you need this clipping path to align with the shape underneath.. so that generally means zooming in and carefully positioning the path.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why wouldnt you just copy, and expand copy then shapebuild the mask?

Comment: yeah.. could @joojaa I was just winging it quickly. And explaining those steps is much more for a new user to follow... but you're right `:)`